# Web-sites and apps for transporting small things in cars going in required direction

Tags: web-apps

I've seen once a web-site (but now can't find it) which connected people who need to transport some small things with drivers who have enough free space in their cars and who go in the desired direction. Do you know similar sites and/or mobile apps? The region in which they operate doesn't really matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Note that we don't recommend websites here. As for apps, you forgot to specify the OS (Android? iOS?), and also your budget if it comes to paid solutions. Can you please [edit] your question and adjust it accordingly? Then, if it's for Android, I might know an app (if I find it again ;)